# How to parse items from JSON and skip invalid entries

Tags: c#, json

I have some JSON Data here - http://backpack.tf/api/IGetPrices/v3/?key=534639d04dd7b85e028b4773

As you can see, the ["response"]["prices"] fields have various other entries, the main things

After the prices token, the next one is 10, not 0 or 1.

What I need to do is, through a loop or something, get all the valid entries which come under `prices` and also get their 6>0>current>value

So like, if in a loop, something like

```
["response"]["prices"][i]["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"]
```

The thing is, I can't get my c# code to ignore the values of 0 and 1 and such. When I run a for loop, it just crashes

How can I make it so it skips the entries which are not there and only takes into consideration the ones which are there??

Comment: Can you share what you already tried? Can you also edit your question so that there are no unfinished sentences? It makes the question hard to read.

Comment: all my tries were fails. I tries using try...catch which didnt work.. also, the sentences are fine

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json), you can extract the data you want with the [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JTokens/JObjects).  It has a method `SelectToken` which allows you to use a path-like syntax to navigate the JSON.  If any token along the path is missing, the method returns null.  So, we can navigate down to the `prices` node and loop over its properties, skipping over the `-1` you consider to be "invalid".  Then for each of remaining properties, use `SelectToken` again to navigate to the `["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"]` if it exists.  If it does, we print the name and value.

```
JObject root = JObject.Parse(json);
JObject prices = (JObject)root.SelectToken("response.prices");
foreach (JProperty prop in prices.Properties())
{
    if (prop.Name != "-1")
    {
        JToken value = prop.Value.SelectToken("6.0.current.value");
        if (value != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Does that help?